# Sort by DESC works, ASC doesn't?

Tags: order, pre-get-posts

I've looked but don't think this is a duplicate question. So I have custom posts ('Events') that are loading into the loop fine, I am using ACF to give the posts a custom field 'ev_date'. I am using

```
<?php 
function setEventOrder2( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'ev_date' );
};
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'setEventOrder2' );
?>
```

Using DESC works fine but ASC shows no posts at all.

Here is the rest of the loop code:

```
    <?php
    $date_var = get_field('ev_date'); 
    $time_var = get_field('time');
    $date_string = print_r($date_var, true);
    $time_string = print_r($time_var, true);
    $mydate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date_string);
    $today = date('Ymd');
    if (isset($postCount)) {
      //
    } else {
      $postCount = 0;
    }

    if ($today <= $date_string && $postCount < 4)  {
      $postCount ++;
      ?>
 


<div class='oxy-post homeEvent'>
  
  <div id="div_block-210-22" class="ct-div-block homeEvent_header">
    <img id="image-204-22" class="calIcon1" alt="calendar icon" src="https://planetpurbeck.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cal_icon.png" class="ct-image">
    <div id="div_block-221-22" class="ct-div-block">
      <a id="link-165-22" class="ct-link" href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' target="_self">
        <h2 id="headline-118-22" class="ct-headline homeEventHeadline" style="text-align:left" ><span id="span-119-22" class="ct-span"><?php the_title(); ?></span></h2>
      </a>
      <div id="text_block-128-22" class="ct-text-block" style="margin-top:5px">
      <span id="span-135-22" class="ct-span"><?php echo print_r($mydate->format('j M Y') . " | " . $time_string, true); ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    

    <?php 
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
      ?>
      <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><img src='<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>' class='oxy-post-image' /></a>
      <?php
    }
    ?>

    <div class='oxy-post-content'>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

    <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='oxy-read-more'>Read More</a>
</div>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: what is the format of the dates in that field?

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the ACF settings for the field

Comment: ok but does that mean the actual value in the database is `Ymd`? Or `d/m/Y`?Have you tried inspecting the value directly to check this? The format of the date is important for sorting. For all we know, ACF stores it as a number then converts it to Ymd when saving/displaying

Comment: From ACF: "The date format that is returned when loading the value. Please note that the value is always saved as Ymd (YYYYMMDD) in the database."